# older version =* (right join) not accepting in new version

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

Below is the old query which is not working in the current version.

```
select b.location,
       case when cmailid is null then cmail else cmailid end as cname,
       b.role,
       a.cmailid,  
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.date_cert, 101) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), a.date_cert, 22), 11)) as certdate,
       c.order1,  
       cast(exception as varchar(100)) as exception, 
       isnull(convert(varchar(50),a.date_cert,113),'') as statusForLink, 
       '' as statusForGrid 
from tbl_sc_details a, 
     tbl_sc_admin b, 
     tbl_sc_roleorder c 
where a.location=*b.location
  and b.role=c.role 
  and b.role='LOG' 
  and quart='4th QUARTER' 
  and year='2016'
```

hope it's due to the join notations(=*)  ,PLease help to get an alternative

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Are you getting an error? Wrong data? What's the compatibility level of your database? What DB engine are you using, and in what version? Do you understand *exactly* what the query is supposed to be doing? If yes, why don't you rewrite it properly? If not, what are you expecting from us?

Comment: not getting any error, getting wrong data, Need to upgrade it to higher version

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: How do you know the problem is with the SQL server version and not your query? Are you comparing the results from an older server with results on the newer server? What are your expected results based on some data? And again, can you explain what the query is supposed to be doing?

Comment: we were getting proper data when it was in old server, after migrating to new upgrading to new server(2012) we are getting error in join

Comment: First you say not getting and error and  now you say getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Change the legacy syntax to `ANSI` syntax

```
 SELECT b.location,
       CASE
           WHEN cmailid IS NULL THEN cmail
           ELSE cmailid
       END AS cname,
       b.role,
       a.cmailid,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.date_cert, 101) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), a.date_cert, 22), 11)) AS certdate,
       c.order1,
       cast(exception AS varchar(100)) AS exception,
       isnull(convert(varchar(50),a.date_cert,113),'') AS statusForLink,
       '' AS statusForGrid
FROM tbl_sc_details a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_sc_admin b 
    ON a.location=b.location
INNER JOIN tbl_sc_roleorder c 
    ON b.role=c.role
WHERE b.role='LOG'
  AND quart = '4th QUARTER'
  AND YEAR='2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper JOINS. The =* and *= are non standard JOIN.

=* stands for the right outer join and *= is used for left outer join.

You can better use the explicit JOINS to join your table.

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx#_where_clause):

> Specifies an outer join using the nonstandard product-specific syntax
>   and the WHERE clause. The *= operator is used to specify a left outer
>   join and the =* operator is used to specify a right outer join.

You can try like this:

```
SELECT b.location,
       CASE
           WHEN cmailid IS NULL THEN cmail
           ELSE cmailid
       END AS cname,
       b.role,
       a.cmailid,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.date_cert, 101) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), a.date_cert, 22), 11)) AS certdate,
       c.order1,
       cast(exception AS varchar(100)) AS exception,
       isnull(convert(varchar(50),a.date_cert,113),'') AS statusForLink,
       '' AS statusForGrid
FROM tbl_sc_details a
RIGHT JOIN tbl_sc_admin b 
    ON a.location=b.location
INNER JOIN tbl_sc_roleorder c 
    ON b.role=c.role
WHERE b.role='LOG'
  AND quart = '4th QUARTER'
  AND YEAR='2016'
```

Comment: @Hardy - You got to give sample data and your expected and current output based on answers so we can know what do you mean by `wrong data`

Answer (score 0):

Time to `ANSI`.

```
SELECT b.location, 
       CASE WHEN cmailid IS NULL 
            THEN cmail 
            ELSE cmailid 
       END AS cname,
       b.role, 
       a.cmailid,  
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.date_cert, 101) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), a.date_cert, 22), 11)) AS certdate,
       c.order1,  
       CAST(exception AS varchar(100)) AS exception, 
       ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),a.date_cert,113),'') AS statusForLink, 
       '' AS statusForGrid 
FROM tbl_sc_details a
RIGHT JOIN tbl_sc_admin b ON a.location = b.location
INNER JOIN tbl_sc_roleorder c ON b.role = c.role 
WHERE b.role = 'LOG' 
AND quart = '4th QUARTER' 
AND year = '2016'
```

If you are still getting the wrong data with the ANSI compliant query then you need to rethink your joins/parameters.